# Should you define a variable that only contains digits as string if you're not going to do any math operation?

Tags: c#

in C# should you define a variable that only contains digits as string if you're not going to do any math operations on that variable? Obviously you have to make sure when setting the variable, you would only accept numbers. The benefit of using int as opposed to string is that compiler does the check for you. I'm just curious what other people think.

Comment: Examples please and context also.

Comment: You should be using the primitive data type necessary to store what you need.  If you need to store a numeric value, you should use a numeric data type.  This goes beyond what the application is doing.  This would show intent in your code of what you need it to do.

Comment: It depends on your data. Integers have a limited range and cannot represent long numbers like phone numbers.

Answer (score 0):

No, definitely not. It uses more memory and there is a reason number data types exist.

EDIT: Also, at some point you're possibly going to want to add some mathematical operations the your code. If you defined the variable as a string, you would have to make more modifications to the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the primitive data type necessary to store what you need. If you need to store a numeric value, you should (most often) use a numeric data type.

This question goes beyond any specific programming language. The question you are asking is how do you want to show your intent within your code to handle some form of data.

For this case, your data is a sequence of digits.

What you need to ask is what is the purpose of this value you are storing.

- What is the upper limit for this data?
- Does formatting matter?
- Do leading zeros have significance?

Answering these questions will assist you in making the best choice for your implementation.

Is there any advantage to using a String data type for this case?

Answer (score 0):

One other point to consider is whether the variables will be used for sorting or comparing. For example, integers as text do not sort the same as integers - "6" would be considered greater than "59".